# Can not understand POST request Format

Tags: c#, rest, webrequest

these are lines from this article https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes

I want to upload video using this explaianation

**Upload File** 
Uploads the file content along with its metadata information.

POST : {{contentUrl}}/nodes?suppress={suppress}

suppress : (Optional)

deduplication: disables checking for duplicates when uploading
Body Parameters:

Multi-form part

--------- metadata ------------

name (required) : file name. Max to 256 Characters. 
kind (required) : "FILE" 
labels (optional) : Extra information which is indexed. For example the value can be "PHOTO" 
properties (optional) : List of properties to be added for the file. 
parents(optional) : List of parent Ids. If no parent folders are provided, the file will be placed in the default root folder. 
---------content ------------

File Bytes

**Sample Request:**

POST /cdproxy/nodes?localId=testPhoto
HTTP/1.1
Host: content-na.drive.amazonaws.com
Authorization: Bearer
Atza|IQEBLjAsAhReYeezFcFdYzqrFOJGv3EG

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{"name":"fooo.jpg","kind":"FILE"}
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content";
filename="db5df4870e4e4b6cbf42727fd434701a.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C

**cURL Request:**

curl -v -X POST --form
'metadata={"name":"testVideo1","kind":"FILE"}' --form
'content=@sample_iTunes.mp4'
'https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/nodes?localId=testVideo1&suppress=deduplication'
--header "Authorization: Bearer
Atza|IQEBLjAsAhQ5zx7pKp9PCgCy6T1JkQjHHOEzpwIUQM"

I have written following code in c#
//FileName 1: File from Computer
//FileName 2:File to be named on amazon cloud.

```
   if (AccessCode == null)
        {
            return ;
        }
        WebRequest request =                 WebRequest.Create(EndPointUrl+"//+&suppress=deduplication'");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string code = "Bearer " + AccessCode;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", code);
        string postData =@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""metadata""   {""name"":"""+FileName1+@""",""kind"":""+FILE""}
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""content"";
        filename="""+FileName2+@"""
        Content-Type: video/wmv";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

The problem is i can't translate it correctly. it is giving 404 error.

> {"message":"Resource does not exist."}

Kindly help me to understand it.

Comment: its a normal `multipart/form-data` POST request with first parameter value is `Stringified` JSON object and second one is a image file

Comment: so there will be two headers?

Comment: No there will be two multipart of the request. I would suggest you to use the new HttpClient APi available in .NET 4.5 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a normal `multipart/form-data` POST request with first parameter value is `Stringified` JSON object and second one is a image file.

Please have a look at : [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

then you can

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("metadata", "{\"name\":\"fooo.jpg\",\"kind\":\"FILE\"}");
HttpUploadFile("THE_URL_HERE", @"C:\test\fooo.jpg", "content", "image/jpeg", nvc);
```

Comment: Thankyou but remote server returned 404

Comment: @Charlie the 404 must be due to some technical amazon thing.